# Hadoop Single node cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new to Ubuntu. Working on setting up a Hadoop single node cluster by following the instructions from [Hadoop Docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html)

The following example copies the unpacked `conf` directory to use as input and then finds and displays every match of the given regular expression.

```
$ mkdir input  
$ cp etc/hadoop/*.xml input  
$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.9.0.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

Fails with the error :

```
bin/hadoop: line 169: /usr/java/latest/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I've tried a bunch of things from answers  to similar issues, but none seemed to work.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are probably better to ask here: https://superuser.com This is unlikely a programming-related question, more about handling / installing software.

Comment: Probably is. I have done as you suggested, but i don't seem to be having luck there either.

Comment: Is your JAVA_HOME set correctly ? Do `hdfs dfs` commands work from your console ?

Comment: I asume you already installed java via `sudo apt-get install default-jre` if not you should do so . 

Once this is done make sure your java command in your path is referencing the right location `which java `  and finally export JAVA_HOME variable  as @philantrovert suggested

Comment: @Joel B - Yes I installed java using sudo apt-get install default-jre.   which java gives me /usr/bin/java. The path in etc/environment has PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

Comment: @philantrovert hdfs dfs does not work from my console. It gives me the same error. I edited etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh and added the following export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
in etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

Thanks for directing me guys!